# How to "inject" a additional where clause into a given nHibernate linq?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a given linq-sql like this:

```
var erg = from p in m_session.Query<LovTestData>()
          select new
          {
              SomeString = p.SomeString,
              SomeOtherString = p.SomeOtherString
          };
```

This should be the "base"-query for a Lov-Dialog. So this is the query which defines the content of the Lov.

But there are fields in the LOV to search. So this is the query I have to use to fill the Lov at runtime:

```
var erg = from p in m_session.Query<LovTestData>()
          where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(someStringValueFilter) || p.SomeString.ToLower().Contains(someStringValueFilter.ToLower())) &&
                 (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someOtherStringFilter) || p.SomeOtherString.ToLower().Contains(someOtherStringFilter.ToLower())))
          select new
          {
              SomeString = p.SomeString,
              SomeOtherString = p.SomeOtherString
          };
```

So I wonder how its possible to "inject" the where clause afterwards into the given query? This is how I think it should look like:

```
var erg = from p in m_session.Query<LovTestData>()
          select new
          {
              SomeString = p.SomeString,
              SomeOtherString = p.SomeOtherString
          };
var additionalWhere = ... //Some way to define this part: ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(someStringValueFilter) || p.SomeString.ToLower().Contains(someStringValueFilter.ToLower())) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someOtherStringFilter) || p.SomeOtherString.ToLower().Contains(someOtherStringFilter.ToLower())))

erg = InjectWhere(erg, additionalWhere); //In this function the where is inserted into the linq so the  result is the second query.
```

Updated:

The additionalWhere should be constructed out of the original query. So its not possible for me to write "p.SomeString" because the construction of the additionalWhere is universal. This is the way I get the fields

```
Type elementType = erg.ElementType;
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in elementType.GetProperties())    
{
    //pi.name...
}
```

Comment: did you ever try this ? 
from p in m_session.Query<LovTestData>().Where(conditions)

Comment: @Waayd: This I have seen already. But I dont know how to define the conditions, because they should be constructed at runtime. So I have to construct them out of the query. Ill update the question to make this clear.

Comment: Conditions will be a lambda expression like x=> string.isnullorempty(x.somedats). If you never used lambda you have to look some example of lambda

Comment: @Waayd: The problem is the dynamic nature of it. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If Query returns IQueryable then there is no problem at all.

```
List<LovTestData> GetTestData(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    var erg = from p in m_session.Query<LovTestData>()
              select new
              {
               ...
              }

    IQueryable result = erg.Where(where);
    return result.ToList();   
}
```

Now. IQueryable will NOT EXECUTE unitl you really use it. So you can do select, where, union and so on, but until you use the IQueryable it won't do anything. Here the real SQL will run in: result.ToList(). That's why you can build all there conditions earlier. Of course assuming that m_session.Query returns IQueryable but as far as I remember - it does.

So you can even do this without result variable that I have created. Just operate on erg.

Waayd's comment will also work.

OK, now about creating filter dynamically. 
Let's take a simple class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's create a list of records - database.

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Name = "Adam Abc", Age = 15},
    new Person {Name = "John Abc", Age = 23},
    new Person {Name = "Steven Abc", Age = 26},
    new Person {Name = "Adam Bca", Age = 21},
    new Person {Name = "Adam Xyz", Age = 26},
};
```

Now, let's prepare a filter. You have to get filter data from a view, now let's just simulate this:

```
string nameIs = "Adam";
bool createAgeFilter = true;
int ageFilterMin = 20;
int ageFilterMax = 25;
```

So we need all Adam's that are in age between 20 and 25. Let's create this condition:

First condition on name:

```
Func<Person, bool> whereName = new Func<Person, bool>((p) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameIs))
        return p.Name.Contains(nameIs);
    else
        return true;
}
);
```

Next condition on age:

```
Func<Person, bool> whereAge = new Func<Person, bool>((p) =>
{
    if (createAgeFilter)
        return p.Age >= ageFilterMin && p.Age <= ageFilterMax;
    else
        return true;
}
);
```

Next, let's have our IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<Person> q = list.AsQueryable();
```

And finally let's add where clauses:

```
List<Person> filteredList = q.Where(whereName)
                             .Where(whereAge)
                             .ToList();
```

That's it. The idea behind this is that you have to create several partial where clauses. Each for one thing you want to filter. But what I've done at the end will make "AND" between the filters. If you would like to "OR" them, you should do it in one other filter type - like in age filter.

I've just came up with this idea. So there may be a better solution. Maybe even some one liner.

**Edit**
If you can't use linq like that, there is another way. But not so simple. 
There MUST be a point somewhere in your application that you build filter in LINQ style. For example in your view. So take this expression and call ToString(). You will get string representation of the linq query.

The next thing you have to do is to install Roslyn package. 
Finally you can change string representation of LINQ expression to LINQ expression using some Roslyn magic:

```
public async static Task<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> ExpressionFromStr<T>(string expressionStr)
{
    var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(T).Assembly);
    return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>(expressionStr, options);
}
```

Usings:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting; //roslyn
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting; //roslyn
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks; //for async and Task.
```

Comment: But I dont know how to define the "where", because they should be constructed at runtime. So I have to construct them out of the query. Ill update the question to make this clear.

Comment: Oh I see now. You have to create it dynamically. I'll try to make something up, and let you know

Comment: @ Adam Jachocki :Youve nailed it. This is exactly my problem.

Comment: The problem is, that I cant use "p.Name" in the definition of the where. As this should work with a unknown query I cant use linq-syntax. As you can see in the updated part of the question I only have the name of the column as a string.

Comment: So, I hope that this time my edit will answer your question :)

Comment: ok, sry for the delay. Im not quite sure if I understand correctly. So the plan is - as I understand - to converte the linq into a sql-string, than insert the additional where and afterwards convert it back into linq? Correct?

Comment: Not quite. You told that you cannot create linq query. So you can create linq query as string. Then you convert this string to proper linq query.

Comment: @Gener4tor Dynamic LINQ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries